# How to get the key in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the messages data under a specific key. But I don't how to get the key. Please help, I'm new to firebase.

In my case right now, I want to get the key encircled below.

I have tried this code below but this returns "chat-mates" not the key.

[image]

```
final DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chat").child("single-chat").child("converstation").child("chat-mates");

    ref.orderByChild("receiverName").equalTo("Liza Soberano").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                String key = child.getKey();
                Log.e("Key", key);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have tried this code below but this returns "chat-mates" not the key.

Answer (score 6):

You must be using `DataSnapshot` method to access the JSON tree.
The `DataSnapshot` element has a method called `getKey()`. That returns the key of an object.

Official Doc: [DataSnapShot getKey() method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DataSnapshot#getKey())

*Example Code:*

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot objSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Object obj = objSnapshot.getKey();
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError firebaseError) {
                Log.e("Read failed", firebaseError.getMessage());
            }
        });
```

In your case, first get to the child node "conversation" and then apply the above method `getKey()`.

Comment: I have tried using DataShapshot, but i don't know how to acheive the logic based on my json tree. I have edited my question above by the way. @AseedUsmani

Comment: Then go to the parent node then use `getKey()` method since chat-mates is really the key of the DataSnapshot that you are in.

Comment: You can use getRef().getKey() for that purpose. Unfortunately I do not have Firebase App setup on my system at the moment, so you have to test it yourself @elbertrivas

Comment: Thank you for your response. My real problem here is my json structure. I changed it as what Frank suggested and then I was able to easily retrieve the data. @AseedUsmani

Answer (score 1):

You're building your path wrong and likely end up iterating a different part of the tree, one level above `child-mates`. In that case it would be correct that `child-mates` is a child key.

The problem is in the last `child()` call when you create the ref:

```
final DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("chat")
    .child("single-chat")
    .child("converstation")
    .child("chat-mates");
```

There is no child `chat-mates` under `converstation`, so this ref won't be correct.

You probably want to do this:

```
final DatabaseReference ref =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
    .child("chat")
    .child("single-chat")
    .child("converstation");

ref.orderByChild("chat-mates/receiverName")
    .equalTo("Liza Soberano")
    .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
```

This will filter on the `chat-mates/receiverName` child of each chat.

Note that you're going against one of Firebase's recommendations with this data structure. Firebase recommends against nesting data types in the way you do here.

A more denormalized data model would be:

```
chat-mates
  $chatRoomId
    receiverName
    senderName
chat-messages
  $chatRoomId
    $messageId
```

This way you can get the mates/participants in a chat, without accessing (or even needing to have access to) the messages themselves.

Comment: This solved my problem.  I realized how complicated my json structure is. Thank you so  much. @Frank van Puffelen